# nginx + php-fpm + v8js crashing

Tags: nginx, php, php-fpm

I have a problem concerning v8js extension for php. I needed to install it on my server (and did) (CentOS 6.5, Nginx 1.0.15, php 5.5.12)

but whenever I give such a simple test to it: http://pastebin.com/KtyLYccs

it crashes php-fpm child process

```
[11-Jul-2014 15:45:44] WARNING: [pool www] child 19409 exited on signal 11 (SIGSEGV) after 159.191070 seconds from start
[11-Jul-2014 15:45:44] NOTICE: [pool www] child 19577 started
```

any ideas what may have gone wrong? also whatever logs/configs you need, just tell and I'll share them with you

Answer (score -1):

found solution, you need to have php compiled without ZTS enabled

Comment: Could you please elaborate on how you managed to sort it out?

Comment: The problem was that PHP was compiled with flag '--enable-maintainer-zts' which was done because of some old requirement for pthreads to work. what you need to do is firstly check if you have zts maintainer enabled in your phpinfo() and if yes, then you'll have to recompile whole php with that flag disabled (which is disabled by default, just don't add this '--enable-maintainer-zts' to your ./configure)